# Find marginal probability using bivariate normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

I'm given two variables $\begin{bmatrix} X_{1}\\{X_2} \end{bmatrix} \sim N_2({\mu}=\begin{bmatrix} 2\\-5\end{bmatrix},\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 1&{-0.5}\\{-0.5}&4 \end{bmatrix})$

How would I calculate $P(X_1 > 0)$?

My only thoughts are to calculate the marginal distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$, if I want to find anything about the probabilities of these variables taking on certain values.

Are there any other methods I can use to find these probabilities?

Comment: How much do you know about the bivariate normal distribution? For instance, are you aware that the marginal distributions are 1-dimensional normal distributions? You can actually read the parameters directly from $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, which in your example gives $X_1 \sim N(2,1)$ and $X_2 \sim N(-5,4)$.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Wow, I hadn't realised that - cheers. I thought the middle term in the expansion would force some sort of dependence.

Comment: and there is a dependence in the joint distribution, which in this case is that $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=-0.5$. This dependence does however not change the fact that the marginal distributions are normal.